# Postfix smtp test occured "Relay access denied"

Tags: postfix

I was following the tutorial http://wiki.centos.org/zh/HowTos/postfix_restrictions

but, when I tried to send a mail with smtp, it returns:

```
Connected to XXX.XXX.33.22 (XXX.XXX.33.22).
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail.xxxx.com ESMTP Postfix
HELO mail.xxxx.com
250 mail.xxxx.com
MAIL FROM:<ned@example.com>
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO:<ned@example.com>
554 5.7.1 <ned@example.com>: Relay access denied
```

And, the postfix main.cf setting is `relay_domains =`

Answer (score 3):

If this message is an inbound message and you have accounts setup for ned@example.com, if its a standard non-virtual domain setup, you need to ensure that example.com is on your [mydestination](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mydestination) line, if it's virtual make sure you have a [virtual_mailbox_domains](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_mailbox_domains) entry, and that it points to a file/hash/database table that contains example.com.

If you're testing email outbound (ie someone on your network trying to send mail to ned@example.com, check that the [mynetworks](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mynetworks) line contains a reference to your networks rfc1918 range (eg 10.0.0.0/8 or 192.168.0.0/24) or that you have enabled and are using [SASL authentication.](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html)

Comment: Thanks! With the `mynetworks` setting all works great!